# Disable a select box after load as well as on change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a number of select boxes that set a specific start and end time when a category option is chosen. However I've managed to put together the function that runs with an `on` `change` event, which is great when I'm creating the event, but I want to also call it when I'm editing the same event.

```js
    $(document).on('change', '#js_sub', function() {
       var GetValue = $(this).val();
       var GetSlots = GetValue.charAt(GetValue.length - 1);
         var shouldEnable = GetSlots == 'Y';
            if (shouldEnable){
       $("select[name='start_time_hour']:eq(0)").val('09');
       $("select[name='start_time_minute']:eq(0)").val('30');
       $("select[name='end_time_hour']:eq(0)").val('15');
       $("select[name='end_time_minute']:eq(0)").val('00');
           }
       $('#js_start_time_hour option:not(:selected)').prop('disabled', shouldEnable);
       $('#js_start_time_minute option:not(:selected)').prop('disabled', shouldEnable);
       $('#js_end_time_hour option:not(:selected)').prop('disabled', shouldEnable);
       $('#js_end_time_minute option:not(:selected)').prop('disabled', shouldEnable);
      });
```

```html
 <select id="#js_sub">
       <option value="01_Y">Day Slot</option>
       <option value="02_N">Anytime</option>
    </select>
    
    <select id="#js_start_time_hour">
       <option value="06">06</option>
       <option value="07">07</option>
       ...
    </select>
    
    <select id="#js_start_time_minute">
       <option value="00">00</option>
       <option value="05">05</option>
       ...
    </select>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I am also checking the last character of the `#js_sub` value to see if it's either a `Y` or `N` which is just a way of me calling a second value for another unrelated script.

Any guidance on how to run this on load as well as on change would be great

EDIT Based on comments:

I did some reading based on the advice below and I put the following together and it does work:

```
var SlotsFunction = function() {
            var GetValue = $("#js_sub").val();
            var GetSlots = GetValue.charAt(GetValue.length - 1);
            var shouldEnable = GetSlots == 'Y';
            if (shouldEnable){
                $("select[name='start_time_hour']:eq(0)").val('09');
                $("select[name='start_time_minute']:eq(0)").val('30');
                $("select[name='end_time_hour']:eq(0)").val('15');
                $("select[name='end_time_minute']:eq(0)").val('00');
            }
                $('#js_start_time_hour option:not(:selected)').prop('disabled', shouldEnable);
                $('#js_start_time_minute option:not(:selected)').prop('disabled', shouldEnable);
                $('#js_end_time_hour option:not(:selected)').prop('disabled', shouldEnable);
                $('#js_end_time_minute option:not(:selected)').prop('disabled', shouldEnable);
            }

        $(document).ready(SlotsFunction);
        $("#js_sub").change(SlotsFunction);
```

Comment: Just get the body of the function and declare your own function then call it both on `.ready()` and `.change()`.

Comment: Thank you very much @IvankaTodorova I took your advice and produced the edit above please let me know if this is what you meant, because it works!

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I meant. Good job!